# forcing session expiry on browser close with django-social-auth

Tags: django, session-timeout, django-sessions

I am looking for a way to force a re-login when a user who has logged in using FB/Google onto my site closes the browser. I was reading https://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html, and I don't think:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_EXPIRATION = 'expires'
```

or

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_SESSION_EXPIRATION = True
```

really does what I am looking for. I tried to add a custom pipeline this way which sets expiry time to 0 as the last thing in the pipelines:

```
def expire_session_on_browser_close(backend, details, response, social_user, uid, user, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.session.set_expiry(0)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    #'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
    'useraccount.pipeline.expire_session_on_browser_close',
)
```

But it doesn't seem to take effect. Setting

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

has no effect either.

On a similar note, my site also allows user to login "traditionally" and I am able to have

```
request.session.set_expiry(0)
```

do the trick there, and users are forced to login when they close the browsers. Just doesn't work with FB/Google logins.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

If I go and muck around with:

```
UserSocialAuthMixin::expiration_datetime()
```

from

```
db\base.py
```

and force it to return 0, my issue gets resolved.

But this is bad, bad hackery. Is there a better, more elegant way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Oh man, I over-engineered to this to the Nth degree. All I needed to do was set:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_SESSION_EXPIRATION=False
```

This way if the Provider's response contains 'expires' or whatever SOCIAL_AUTH_EXPIRATION contains, django-social-auth won't call set_expiry() on that parsed value.

Additionally, I also set the pipeline function (as seen in my original question) so that I could set my own expiry (0 in my case).